# Plot antiderivative of function in R

Tags: r, plot

In my homework i have to plot an antiderivative of a function.
The function:

```
newF <- function(x) {0.75 - 0.75*x^2}
```

Now i need to get the antiderivative of it. I can get the integral between an upper and lower value like this:

```
newFVec <- Vectorize(newF) #Vectorize F to get a valid input for plot method
F <- function(t) {integrate(newF, lower = -2, upper = 2)$value} # get integral between -2 and 2

FVec <- Vectorize(F) #Vectorize the antiderivative


plot(FVec, type="b", from = -2, to = 2, lty = 1, col = "blue") #try to plot FVec
```

If i do this, it just draws a line at 4/3. Which would be correct of course. But what i need is a plot which shows me the values for every value x i´d be putting in the Function. (From range -1 to 1) Or to simply say: I need x as upper value and -1 as lower value.

I know i could just define the antiderivative of f, but the homework says it wants `FVec` to be calculated only by the definition of `integrate()`. How can i go about this? I really searched for it but every case was too specific. I really hope you can help me with this.

Comment: `Vectorize(newF)` is redundant. Your function is already vectorised.

Comment: "Error in curve(expr = x...  : 'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n' ". This comes up now.

Comment: It doesn’t for me. You’re doing something else differently. I mean, the code you’ve shown doesn’t use your `newFVec` anyway.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely correct. I thought you meant `FVec <- Vectorize(F)´

Comment: I am getting a line corresponding to `-1` not `4/3`

Comment: The primitive should be defined as `F <- function(t) {integrate(newF, lower = -2, upper = t)$value}`